# Is it possible to prevent reassignment of variables non-transitively in D2?

Tags: d

Is it possible to prevent reassignment of variables non-transitively in D2?

For example:

```
final int[] a = [0];
a[0] = 1; // OK.
a = []; // ERROR.
```

I only see `const` and `immutable` here:
http://www.dlang.org/const3.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. What you have is `const` and `immutable`, and they are transitive (they really wouldn't work if they weren't). You can do

```
const(int)[] a = [0];
a[0] = 1; // ERROR.
a = []; // OK;
```

But not what you're looking for.

The compiler can give better guarantees when `const` and `immutable` are transitive. Also, `immutable` really isn't of any use for threading (one of its main reasons for existing) unless it's transitive, and because anything that's `immutable` must be able to be `const`, `const` must be transitive as well. So, of necessity, they can't be used for simply protecting against variable reassignment. And there are no other constructs in the language for doing so.